# Regex to split lines from a file

Tags: php, regex

I can have a line like this

`BK0001 PHP and MySQL Web Development (4th Edition) $49.95 (Clearance Price!)`

or 
 `BK0013 Wanna be a Master at PHP? (Free!)`

I want to split like `[BK0001] ][PHP and MySQL Web Development (4th Edition)] [$49.95] [(Clearance Price!)]`
or 
`[BK0013] [Wanna be a Master at PHP?] [(Free!)]`
  The regex I'm using is:

```
$re = '~^(?<id>\S+)\s+(?<title>.*?)\s+(?<price>\$\d[\d.]*)\s*(?<clearance>.*)$~';
```

However when used in my code,

```
 foreach ($bookFile as $book) {
                $re = '~^(?<id>\S+)\s+(?<title>.*?)\s+(?<price>\$\d[\d.]*)\s*(?<clearance>.*)$~';
                if (preg_match($re, $book, $parts)) {
                    $b_price = substr($parts['price'], 1);
                    $bookObj = new Book($parts['id'], $parts['title'], number_format($b_price, 2), $parts['clearance']);
                    array_push($bookList, $bookObj);
                }
            }
```

I'm unable to get any free books. How can I also get free books using regex?

Comment: Try `'~^(?<id>\S+)\s+(?<title>.*?)(?:\s+(?<price>\$\d[\d.]*))?\s*(?<clearance>\([^()]*\))$~'`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/DhnE5R/1).

Comment: Can free be part of price? nothing is showing at all which is weird...

Comment: Just put a question mark after `(?<price>\$\d[\d.]*)` to indicate that the group is optional

Comment: How do you describe each part you need to extract? What can there be? `(Free)` looks more like the clearance due to parentheses.

Comment: If you need an answer, please provide feedback. What kind of chars each *field* can consist of? What contexts can help separate one field from another?

Comment: I decided to learn regex and split it into 4 parts to search in the string. so I made 4 regex expressions instead of just one which solved the issue. Thanks for your input and previous answer, it has helped me come up with them.

Answer (score 0):

Since it helped you, I will post the expression:

```
'~^(?<id>\S+)\s+(?<title>.*?)(?:\s+(?<price>\$\d[\d.]*))?\s*(?<clearance>\([^()]*\))$~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DhnE5R/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?<id>\S+)` - Group "id": 1+ non-whitespace chars
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespace chars
- `(?<title>.*?)` - Group "title": any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `(?:\s+(?<price>\$\d[\d.]*))?` - an optional group:

  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespace chars
  - `(?<price>\$\d[\d.]*)` - Group "price": `$`, a digit and then 0+ digits or `.`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?<clearance>\([^()]*\))` - Group "clearance": `(`, 0+ chars other than `(` and `)` and then `)`
- `$` - end of string.